# MYSQLの再インストール

Tags: mysql

現在MYSQLをソースからインストールしており、
今回、MYSQLにSSLで接続する必要が出てきたためmysqlを以下の手順で再インストールしようと考えております。
この場合現在あるデータベースのデータに影響はありますでしょうか？

```
cd /usr/loca/src/mysql-5.7.11
; -DWITH_SSL=yesを追加
cmake . -DDEFAULT_CHARSET=utf8 -DDEFAULT_COLLATION=utf8_general_ci -DWITH_SSL=bundled -DDOWNLOAD_BOOST=1 -DWITH_BOOST=/usr/local/src/boost_1_60_0/boost -DWITH_SSL=yes
make
porg -lD "make install"
```

my.cnfに以下を追加※httpdで使用しているssl証明書を使用する

```
[mysqld]
ssl-ca = /opt/httpd/httpd-2.4.18/conf/ssl.crt/server-ca.crt
ssl-cert = /opt/httpd/httpd-2.4.18/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt
ssl-key = /opt/httpd/httpd-2.4.18/conf/ssl.key/server.key
```

```
service mysqld restart
```

ssl適応確認

```
mysql -u root -p -e "show variables like '%ssl%'"
```

```
cat /proc/version
  Linux version 2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b8.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Dec 15 21:19:08 UTC 2015
mysql --version
  mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.11, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL関連以外に全く変更がないのであれば、影響はありません。

ただし、自分でソースコードからビルドしているとその「全く変更がない」事を保証できるかという話になってきますので、念のためデータベースのフルバックアップを取得しておくこと、作業前後のデータの整合性の確認方法、バックアップからのリカバリ方法を検討しておくことをお勧めします。

また、どうしても必要が無い限りソースコードからのビルドではなく、MySQL公式かディストリビュータが提供しているバイナリパッケージを利用されることも検討した方がよいでしょう。